# what should be tested when application should support other browser like chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, gwt

assume we have the following scenario:

We have an application which supports only firefox only. The applications uses GWT. Some customer requires that the application should also support chrome browser as well. New permutation was compiled for chrome as well.

Question: What should be tested to ensure that we have same functionality on the new browser and how? Should we just start application with the new browser and check page by page and function by function?

Answer (score 1):

Like you say, you would need to check each page and function.

In my experience, when the app does not explicitly style a visual element, the browser's base style for that element is used, and in some cases that can differ a little between browsers, as each browser has a slightly different base CSS.  So, depending on your app, you might find things sized or positioned or colored differently.

Comment: This is the correct answer. Normally when using GWT 98% of the stuff will work fine. But some special CSS, some special native javascript may look different on Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

It shouldn't be necessary to test any differences.

From [GWT's overview](http://www.gwtproject.org/overview.html):

> Its goal is to enable productive development of high-performance web applications without the developer having to be an expert in browser quirks, XMLHttpRequest, and JavaScript.

So, unless you do some fancy things, all should work the same way, no matter which browser is used.

Comment: I don't think so. for example  "&#013;" Is working for firefox but not for chrome. I had to replace it with "&#010;"

Comment: @Ronald Just out of curiosity: what is the use case that you need to distinguish line endings in HTML?